# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 86010 > 65536)

Tags: java, android-studio

I don't know what the error means. I'm trying to do an uber app from youtube that uses Firebase and got this error.

> Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 86010 > 65536)
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete.
>
> > build.gradle(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.ezbusjava"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                debuggable = true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }
```

> build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Enabling Multidex in the app. You can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

Android has a 65,536 method limit. If your app exceeds that number, you need to enable [multidexing](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).

Simply add the `multiDexEnabled` flag and the needed dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Additionally, you need to configure your app to make use of multidexing.

According to the docs, if your app extends `Application`, you need it to extend from `MultiDexApplication` instead.

If your app is not extending `Application`, you need to add the following line to your manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
</application>
```